Images are not displayed on the site after they are sent through the database Laravel Backpack
I encountered a problem that after uploading a photo to the site through the admin panel, the photo appears in the database but does not appear in the public folder for display on the site.
I did not change the filesystem.php after the backpack installation. The only changes were in this file, where the interactions are written
InstagramPostsCrudController.php
protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(InstagramPostsRequest::class);
        CRUD::setFromDb();
        CRUD::field('photo')->type('upload');
    }


as our docs says, please try with
CRUD::field('photo')->type('upload')->withFiles(true);

Make sure you have correctly set the public symlink too
php artisan storage:link

Cheers.

Thank you so much!! Is it possible to upload photos to different directories, for example instaphotos, fbphotos?

Is possible, you have in docs instructions to customize the process
